# PrestaShop 1.7.4.2 - Enable or Disable carrier based on the number of product in the Cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Does anyone know if there is a way to enable or disable a selected carrier in PrestaShop when the amount of product in cart equal to a chosen value.

For example in my project I want to disable a carrier and enable another one when the customer has 12 product in his cart (one of the carrier is related to a module).

Is it possible to modify this in BO, or tpl files ? Or maybe a module exist which can allow to do it ?

I'm using PrestaShop 1.7.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

The PrestaShop Admin Panel allows you to achieve this but only based on price/weight ranges, not the # of products in the shopping cart.

- A proper way would be to [override](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/) methods such as the `getCarriers()` static method in the Carrier class.
- An alternate solution would be to have both of these carriers as [Carrier modules](https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-shipping-module-for-prestashop.html) and then to manage the exceptions directly within these modules

To my knowledge, there is currently no module offering this feature.

I hope this helps!

p.s. You can retrieve the current number of products in the visitor/customer's shopping cart by calling the `getNbProducts()` static method from the Cart class.